# How can i fix this alignment issue with using cat in R, where it keeps aligning a bit to the left instead of right

Tags: r

Im trying to make my output look like this, which shows everything aligned to the right and spaced evenly:
[Expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lJU6.png)

But for some reason my own output ends up being shifted to the left:

```r
Board(playerA, header = TRUE)
   Name    0s   1s   2s   3s   5s   X    Out  Tot 
T Smith    1    1    1    2    2    0    0   19
```

The following code is a matrix with the following properties:

```r
initialise <- function(name) {
  matrix(
    rep(0, 8),
    nrow = 1, 
    ncol = 8,
    byrow = TRUE,
    dimnames = list(name,c("0s", "1s", "2s", "3s", "5s", "X", "Out", "Tot")
    )
  )   
}
```

This here is the code i did in order to print the matrix and cat the column to the word "Name" as well as space it and make it look even:

```r
Board <- function(player, header = FALSE) {
  if (header) {
    cat("   Name   ")

    for (name in colnames(player)) {
      cat(" ")
      cat(format(name, width = 4))
    }
    cat("\n")

    cat(rownames(player))


    for (i in 1:length(player)) {
      cat(" ")
      cat(format(player[i], width = 4))
    }
  }
```

```r
#test code
playerA <- initialise("T Smith")
Board(playerA, header = TRUE)
```

If anyone can help I will really appreciate it!

Comment: @GKi can you be more specific?

Comment: @GKi sorry didnt work ended up making it unaligned

Comment: Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to expand / trim the player name to the width of `cat("   Name   ")` in the header.

```
Board <- function(player, header = FALSE) {
  if (header) {
    cat("   Name")
    
    for (name in colnames(player)) {
      cat(" ")
      cat(format(name, width = 4, justify = "right"))
    }
    cat("\n")
  }
  cat(strtrim(paste(rownames(player), "      "), 7))

  for (i in 1:length(player)) {
    cat(" ")
    cat(format(as.character(player[i]), width = 4, justify = "right"))
  }
}
Board(playerA, header = TRUE)
#   Name   0s   1s   2s   3s   5s    X  Out  Tot
#T Smith    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   0
```

Comment: Just remove the spaces after *Name* and reduce it in `strtrim`. -> See update.